# Download File in Blazor Server Side with Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server Side Web Application that uses the default authorization and authentication.

```
app.UseAuthentication()
app.UseAuthorization()
```

I can protect my pages with

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

I have a login page with anonymous access to authenticate. This works fine.

Now I need a way to let the user download files from this authorized pages. Surprisingly I haven't found any straightforward way to do this.

One workaround is to build an API Controller with the filename as a path argument and give the user a link to it.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FileController{

  [HttpGet("download/{filename}")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Download([FromRoute] string filename){
  
    //Do some checks and get file from Filesystem

    return file;
  }
}
```

And in the .razor file

```
<a href="@CalculateDownloadLink("file.txt")" target="_blank"></a>

private string CalculateDownloadLink(string filename){
  return $"{NavigationManager.BaseUri}/api/file/download/{filename}"
}
```

This is a dumbed down version. In reality the filenames are generic. This works too.

Now I want to add Authentication to the API Controller because I don't want anyone guessing filenames. But I don't know how.

Of Course the [Authorize] Attribute doesn't work because the code is outside the circuit scope.
I can't figure out how to use any build-in Authorization to make this work.

Is there a better way to download files from a Blazor app?

Comment: Blazor has a FileInput component that you can put wherever you want.  I don't think navigating is a very Blazory way to do this.

Comment: I don't want to upload a File, I want to download a File.

Comment: Hmmmm. . . normally, to download a file, you just provide a link to it.  At any rate, I'm assuming you've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/243420/blazor-server-app-downlaod-files-from-server.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answering your question, but `[Authorize]` on the controller should work. Have you tried it? Controller methods get the same cookies that Blazor pages get.

But there is a better way to download a file from Blazor without a need for navigation. See this [blog post](https://www.meziantou.net/generating-and-downloading-a-file-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm).

Comment: I have and it didn't work at all. But it was a year ago and maybe this has been fixed since.  Seems like yours solution is tailored for Blazor Webassembly. I am looking for a solution with Blazor server side.  
But thank you for the suggestions. I will try both when i can spare some time.

Comment: Let me clarify, controllers get the same cookies IF you navigate. If you are making an http request using Refit or HttpClient you will need to manually pass your authentication cookie.

Comment: The blog post is indeed about WASM, but Server should also work the same way. I am doing this very thing in my projects. The gist of it is you have a js function that appends an <a> tag on the page and sets the base64 encoded data that you send via the interop.

Comment: @TinyTownSoftware There is no need to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is not a controller. It does not implement `Controller`...

```
[Authorize]
public class FileController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

FYI: If you add the download attribute to the anchor the file will only download when clicked.

```
<a download href="@CalculateDownloadLink("file.txt")">Download file.txt</a>
```

I made a junk repo that works if you need me to post it.